# Changing materials properties during runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to alter my HDRP Lit material's emissive color and emissive intensity but it does not get reflected on my gameObjects. I have even tried using "_EmissionColor" and still there was no change. However the material that is suppose to change, shows as (Instance). What am I doing wrong here?

```
public GameObject[] myGOs;

private void Start () {
        for(int i = 0; i<myGOs.Length; i++){
            myGOs[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.SetColor("_EmissiveColor", new Vector4(0.8196f,0.783f,0,1) * 3.0f);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check if your material has this property - `material.HasProperty("_EmissiveColor")`

If, so, there is a trick which is usually applied in such cases - enable the keyword:
material.EnableKeyword("_EMISSION");

For your material the keyword can differ. You can find it among all shader keywords using `material.shaderKeywords`